# How do I separate my Apollo/Jest test file into multiple files (executeOperation)?

Tags: testing, server, jestjs, graphql, apollo

I am trying to write tests for my Apollo GraphQL application, but my problem is that I can't find a way to separate the tests into multiple files. The executeOperation method I need to execute queries and mutations is located on the ApolloServer instance object and I don't know how i could access it in other files.

Each time i run jest i want to:

1. Create an instance of MongoMemoryServer and use mongoose to connect to it (which i need to test mutations that updates the database).
2. Start a new apollo-express-server.
3. Run tests in multiple test files using the method executeOperation that is located on the ApolloServer instance variable.
4. Disconnect mongoose, stop MongoMemoryServer and stop the ApolloServer.

I've tried setting up this testing environment using a jest configuration with globalSetup and globalTeardown. But global variables set during the globalSetup can't be accessed in the test files. So there was no way to export the server object.

Iv'e also tried creating a new ApolloServer for every test file using the jest functions "beforeAll" and "afterAll", when I did that my program ended up trying to start multiple servers at once on the same port which obviously did not work.

The Apollo docs mention the "apollo-server-testing" library (which they don't recommend), but its method "createTestClient" also require the server instance so that could not solve my problem.

How can i expose the apollo server instance to my test files? Or maybe there's another way to run GraphQL queries and mutations in my test files without exposing the server at all. I am happy to hear all your suggestions!

Comment: Did you find a solution? 

I am having issues just getting executeOperation working at the moment.... singleResult and/or initialResult are not interactable on my editor / test, but when i run the jest test the value shows in the test. Very confused!

Comment: My solution was creating a jest testEnvironment: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string

In the setup function i made the apollo server instance a global variable so i could access it in the test file. Not an optimal solution but it works.

Comment: Here is some sample code: https://imgur.com/a/bTRarFq
Hope that helps you!